# org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 2 on Startup

Tags: java, jetty, apache-shindig

I am using RHEL 6.5, java 1.7.0_45. Please help me out!

```
2014-09-19 17:34:01.707::WARN:  Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@18329bfc{/,/opt/cisco/jetty/webapps/shindig-server-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war}
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Error while locating instance
  bound to org.apache.shindig.social.sample.spi.JsonDbOpensocialService
  for member at org.apache.shindig.social.sample.oauth.SampleRealm.jsonDbService(SampleRealm.java:43)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$SingleFieldInjector.inject(InjectorImpl.java:486)
        at com.google.inject.BinderImpl$StaticInjection$2.call(BinderImpl.java:463)
        at com.google.inject.BinderImpl$StaticInjection$2.call(BinderImpl.java:461)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:747)
        at com.google.inject.BinderImpl$StaticInjection.runMemberInjectors(BinderImpl.java:460)
        at com.google.inject.BinderImpl.createInjector(BinderImpl.java:285)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:79)
        at org.apache.shindig.common.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceServletContextListener.java:65)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1239)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:466)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:523)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:161)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$ImplicitBinding.get(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
        at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:37)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:756)
        at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:35)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$SingleFieldInjector.inject(InjectorImpl.java:473)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.shindig.social.sample.spi.JsonDbOpensocialService$$FastClassByGuice$$114b7d7.newInstance(<generated>)
        at com.google.inject.cglib.reflect.FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:67)
        at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:142)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 2
        at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:413)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:180)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:420)
    at org.apache.shindig.social.sample.spi.JsonDbOpensocialService.<init>(JsonDbOpensocialService.java:128)
        ... 40 more
```

Comment: Guice cannot create new instance of org.apache.shindig.social.sample.spi.JsonDbOpensocialService. Take a look at original exception - org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 2

Comment: Thanks Joakim for ur comments. But the same shindig-server-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war is deployed successfully on another setup using same Jetty 6.1 in RHEL4. where do i check JSON related stuff ? plz help

Comment: See constructor of JsonDbOpensocialService, line 128

Comment: As I see from sources of shindig(probably a bit different version) empty or not json string is returned by your database. So error is not in jetty itself.